# WebView data exchange in android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm going to build an android application, I'm thinking to make the content of the activities as webview, but if I do that; I'll face major problem of getting information from SQLite database to fill the data into the web view, also I need a mechanism to read all the inputs from the web view and save it somewhere like SQLite database.
Also I need some data to be sent from an activity to another.

May be my question is stupid, and may be the answer is easy, kindly help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a java to javascript bridge.....

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html